# OrderBy gets ignored

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="location in truckDetail.locations track by $index | orderBy:location.startDate" class="locationLoopRow">
   <span class="rowEdit"><i ng-click="location.editMode=!location.editMode"  class="fa {{location.editMode?'fa-ban':'fa-pencil'}}"></i></span>
   <span class="rowDate">{{location.startDate|date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
   <span class="rowDate">{{location.endDate|date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
   <span class="rowLocation">{{location.name}}</span>
</div>
```

The `orderBy` seems to be ignored completely as seen in the screenshot.
[image]

I also tried to solve this by using a sort-function:

```
| orderBy:dateOrderBy(location.startDate)

$scope.dateOrderBy=function(date) {
   return date.getFullYear()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getDate();
},
```

In debug mode I can see that this message returns values like '2015/4/29'. Still: The list isn't sorted at all

Comment: could you add you json data so that I can participate to solve this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `dateOrderBy` function in `ng-repeat`, you only need to specify it's name:

```
| orderBy:dateOrderBy
```

Then in your controller your sort function will receive the `location` object:

```
$scope.dateOrderBy = function(location) {
    return location.startDate;
};
```

Example in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MorL1qxzsqbVgff6AUL6?p=preview).

UPD: this one should work [as well](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKxeOGxZUtv9dxVxTNF1?p=preview):

```
| orderBy:'startDate'
```

UPD 2: `track by $index` should always go [in the end of expression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5520):

```
location in truckDetail.locations | orderBy:'startDate' track by $index
```

Comment: Tried all of your suggestions. Still the same :(

Comment: @OleAlbers Also this issue might be related to `track by $index` that you use. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: @OleAlbers Yep, definitely `track by $index`. Check this one - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5520.

Comment: track by $index was the evil one. Thanks